# Не могу настроить работу фрагментов в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Помогите пожайлуста с отображением Фрагментов на Активити, не работает с этим кодом
Taxi (fragment):
    '

```
public class Taxi extends Fragment {


    Button uber_call;
    Button uber_download;
    Button uklon_download;
    Button uklon_order_online;
    Button taxi_plus_call;
    Button taxi_plus_order_onlinecall;
    Button taxi_plus_download;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uber_call = getView().findViewById(R.id.uber_call);
        uber_download = getView().findViewById(R.id.uber_download);
        uklon_download = getView().findViewById(R.id.uklon_download);
        uklon_order_online = getView().findViewById(R.id.uklon_order_online);
        taxi_plus_call = getView().findViewById(R.id.taxi_plus_call);
        taxi_plus_order_onlinecall = getView().findViewById(R.id.taxi_plus_order_online);
        taxi_plus_download = getView().findViewById(R.id.taxi_plus_download);

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.uber_call:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:9988")), "Call"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.uber_download:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab&hl=en")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.uklon_download:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.uklontaxi&hl=en")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.uklon_order_online:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.uklon.com.ua/")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi_plus_call:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:244")), "Call"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi_plus_order_online:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://taxiplus.ua/")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi_plus_download:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sss.taxi.plus")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        uber_call.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        uber_download.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        uklon_download.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        uklon_order_online.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        taxi_plus_call.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        taxi_plus_order_onlinecall.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        taxi_plus_download.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_taxi, null);
    }
}'
```

Drawer:
 '

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Drawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Taxi taxi;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        taxi = new Taxi();
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

       if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_bus) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_funicular) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_minibus) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_subway) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_city_train) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_tram) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_trolleybus) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_taxi) {
           /*Intent intent = new Intent(Drawer.this, Tax.class);
           startActivity(intent);*/
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, taxi);
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_hotels) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_leisure) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_need_to_know) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_emergencies) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Drawer.this, Emergencies.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

'

Comment: ну как минимум не хватает коммита транкзакции (`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, taxi).commit();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При любом изменении `FragmentTransaction` необходимо вызвать метод `commit()`, чтобы они вступили в силу.

В вашем случае надо добавить к `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, taxi);` метод `commit()`.

Comment: Спасибо, 3 часа вчера мучался